# Embedded google maps iframe in SVG element

Tags: css, iframe, svg, google-maps-api-3

How can i add my google maps into an svg element?
I want to fill svg with map.

The map appears but stretched and out of the svg shape

To teste the code you have to insert an src link in iframe.

My code:

```css
svg
{
  stroke: red;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <foreignObject id="map" width="560" height="349">
    <iframe width="560" height="349" frameborder="0" style="border:0" src="LINK + API_KEY" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </foreignObject>
  <path fill="url(#map)" d="M 50 15, 100 25, 100 100, 50 100, 0 100, 0 25Z" />
</svg>
```

Thank's

Comment: Welcome to SO! When providing sample code, please make it a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (so, give us a working iframe example). I understand correctly your minimal question is can use an svg to mask an iframe, is that right?

Comment: Yes, this is it! I don't show an valid iframe because the api key of google maps.

Comment: Cool. If that's the question, then google maps doesn't really matter and any working iframe would be fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution based on Yoksel's ["Masking video with SVG Clippath"](http://codepen.io/yoksel/pen/oggRwR). The placeholder video is just to provide a working public iframe. To use this solution you'll have to redefine the `<path>` to have the right sizing (if you're lucky, you'll just be able to use percentages like Yoksel did).

(@yoksel are you the same Yoksel?)

```css
.svg {
  width: 560px;
  height: 349px;
}
```

```html
<svg class="svg">
  <clippath id="my-clippath">
    <path d="M 50 15, 100 25, 100 100, 50 100, 0 100, 0 25Z"></path>
  </clippath>

  <g clip-path="url(#my-clippath)">
    <foreignObject width="560" x="0" y="0" height="349">
        <iframe width="560" height="349" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/NpEaa2P7qZI" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </foreignObject>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank's @henry . This is it but how can i put for example the clippath with a width:100% and height:100%? And fit the content.
I'm using a lot of svg shapes and i'm having problems with responsive when i have svg filled with images or in this case with iframes.

Comment: If you're still working on this: looks like some good resources are https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/05/creating-responsive-shapes-with-clip-path/, http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/, and http://codepen.io/maddesigns/full/jJqep